# Socket.EndReceive() and bytes read never 0

Tags: c#, sockets

Form what I read, it seems that there will be a final callback with 0 bytes when the buffer has been read, however I am not seeing this.

In my receive callback function I get the bytes read by calling the `EndReceive().`

I assumed if the bytes read < buffer size another call to `BeginRead()` could trigger the receive callback for the last time with a bytes read of 0. However, this is not the case.

So if bytes read is < buffer size and there is not going to be a callback with 0 bytes....then how do I ensure I will get the last packet on edge cases when the last packet size = buffer size?

Comment: A 0 byte return means the other end has disconnected. You should not be using the buffer size to determine the message length. Whatever service you're using should have a method for determining the length of the message. If you're rolling your own, you need to devise one. It can be an end-of-message marker, a message prefix that contains the length of the message, etc.

Comment: EndReceive will: block if there´s nothing to read, then return the number of bytes read or zero if the other side of the tcp connection closed for send. Also, see previous comment to put an application defined protocol on top of the raw stream.

Comment: A zero byte return means that Keep-Alive is being used.  TCP specification allows a zero byte packet so the connection doesn't get closed when idle.  itsme86 is wrong.  He is correct that you should add to beginning of message a byte count so receiving end knows when all the data has been received.